# How can I transform a single column query output to a multi-column one?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have SQL query that produced more than 1000 rows. How it can get as columns ?

Example:

```
1
2
...
999
1000
```

how can I get as,

```
1         101      ....
2         102   
...       ...
99        199
100       200
```

following code displays

1 2 3 ...100
101 102 103 ...200

I want like this

```
1         101      
2         102   
...       ...
99        199
100       200
```

$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM master_break");

$display = 10;
$cols = 0;
echo "";
while($fetched = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    if($cols == 0){
        echo "\n";
    }
    // put what you would like to display within each cell here
    echo "".$fetched['sName']." | ".$fetched['value']."";
    $cols++;
    if($cols == $display){
        echo "";
        $cols = 0;
    }
}
// added the following so it would display the correct html
if($cols != $display && $cols != 0){
    $neededtds = $display - $cols;
    for($i=0;$i\n";
        echo "
";
    }
     echo "";
    } else {
    echo "";
}
?>

Comment: What for? Where are you querying the database from?

Comment: I don't get it at all. And show us your query. And explain more what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

This will more than likely need to be done in the presentation layer (or display of data). The query can not produce multiple columns from 1 column, so you will ned to display the data as you need it in your code.